# Handling events that cross more than one route using Linear Referencing of QGIS

Tags: qgis-plugins, linear-referencing

I am working on implementing linear referencing.

How would you deal with the situation below?

Where an event is stretched across two or more "routes". At the moment I am playing around with the LRS plugin in QGIS, but hoping to implement it using postGIS only when I am done.

Another similar situation would be road maintenance, where the same project is to improve the road surface for a section that cross multiple roads. So the starting point of a an event can be on route 2 at X meter and end at route 1 at x meter. The examples I have come across so far is using event layers where the event start and stop on the same route, I find it very limiting.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have a table `events` with an `id` and other informations and `route_events`, which, in your example, will have 2 records : one for the route 1 and one for the route 2, referencing the same event ?

Comment: Not 100% I understand if I understand what you mean. But I am looking for a way to treat the event as one continuous line. A user adding an object will only click "event start + event end" and should not need to care for anything else. I don't want the operation/event to be split into many parts.